# How to run huggingface Helsinki-NLP models

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use the Helsinki-NLP models from [`huggingface`](https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en), but
I cannot find any instructions on how to do it.
The README files are computer generated and do not contain explanations.
Can some one point me to a getting started guide, or show an example of how to run a model like opus-mt-en-es?

Answer (score 4):

On the model's page [here](https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en) there's a *Use in Transformers* link that you can use to see the code to load it in their `transformers` package as shown below:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en")
```

then use it as you would any transformer model:

```
inp = "Me llamo Wolfgang y vivo en Berlin"
input_ids = tokenizer(inp, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
outputs = model.generate(input_ids=input_ids, num_beams=5, num_return_sequences=3)
print("Generated:", tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True))
```

Output:

```
Generated: ['My name is Wolfgang and I live in Berlin', 'My name is Wolfgang and I live in Berlin.', "My name's Wolfgang and I live in Berlin."]
```

Answer (score 1):

To use on the fly, you can check the huggingFace course [here](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter1/3?fw=pt). They provide pipelines that help you run this on the fly, consider:

```
translator = pipeline("translation", model="Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en")
translator("your-text-to-translate-here")
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to run the `Helsinki-NLP` models is with [ctranslate2](https://opennmt.net/CTranslate2/index.html) library, as shown [here](https://opennmt.net/CTranslate2/guides/transformers.html#marianmt). This is much faster than using the `transformers` library since `ctranslate2` is optimized for speed.

Downloading the model:

```
ct2-transformers-converter --model Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de --output_dir opus-mt-en-de
```

Running in python:

```py
import ctranslate2
import transformers

translator = ctranslate2.Translator("opus-mt-en-de")
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de")

source = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer.encode("Hello world!"))
results = translator.translate_batch([source])
target = results[0].hypotheses[0]

print(tokenizer.decode(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(target)))
```